# How to use pending and status in useFetch in Nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, fetch-api, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to use either `pending` or `status` with the useFetch composable in Nuxt 3 to disable a button and show a spinner when a POST request is pending like so:

```
const { pending, status, execute } = await useFetch("/notifyme", {
  immediate: false,
  baseURL: config.public.apiBase,
  method: "POST",
  body: {
    email: email.value,
  },
});
```

When using `pending` as below, the button is disabled and spinner is showing by default even before the request has been made:

```
<button
:disabled="pending"
type="submit">
Notify me
<ButtonSpinner v-show="pending" />
</button>
```

When using `status` as below, the button is not disabled and spinner is not showing by when the request is made:

```
<button
:disabled="status==='pending'"
type="submit">
Notify me
<ButtonSpinner v-show="status==='pending'" />
</button>
```

I'm confused as to how to use `pending` and `status` for useFetch and why both of them exist if they are so similar.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an issue using `pending` and `immediate: false` together:

[useFetch/useAsyncData: BUG: when immediate: false, then pending is true before call execute/refresh (must to be false) #19218](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/19218)

As I understand it, this is why the `status` feature was developed.

The reason I couldn't get `status` option to work with my code in my question was that this feature was added in a later version of Nuxt 3 that I didn't have installed yet.

I had to run `nuxi upgrade` to get the latest version of Nuxt 3 with the new `status` feature.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the `pending` and the `status` to work, you need to set `server` to `false`. See example

And, instead of using the `useFetch`, use [`useLazyFetch`](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-lazy-fetch)

Here an example.

```js
const { data, pending, execute, status } = await useLazyFetch('https://catfact.ninja/fact', {
    server: false
})
```

Tested and it works. [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-9dtii5?file=app.vue)

> I'm confused as to how to use pending and status for useFetch and why
> both of them exist if they are so similar.

No, they are not similar. The `pending` only return `true` or `false`. The pending will set to `true` if the API is still loading and become `false` when it is done. For the `status`, this will indicate the status of the data requested. It will output `idle`, `pending`, `success`, and `error`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I see now that there are differences between pending and status.

Comment: `useLazyFetch` is just a wrapper for `useFetch` with the option `lazy: true`